# how to remove grid lines with a button click in fabric.js canvas

Tags: fabricjs

I have to two buttons, one to add grids and another to remove grids.
 When I am clicking add button, I am writing following lines of code:

```
   var gridsize = 5;
   var gridoption={ stroke: "#000000", strokeWidth: 1, selectable:false, strokeDashArray: [5, 5],evented:false};

   for(var x=1;x<(canvas.width/gridsize);x++)
   {
    canvas.add(new fabric.Line([100*x, 0, 100*x, 600],gridoption));
    canvas.add(new fabric.Line([0, 100*x, 600, 100*x],gridoption));
   }
```

With these codes, the grids appear with a click of button,but I also want to remove the grids once another button is clicked without making any change to the other objects in the canvas. Since I am not selecting any object here. remove() is also not working. Please help.

Comment: I have seen the following answer                                                      function RemoveGrid() {
    var objects = canvas.getObjects('line');
    for (let i in objects) {
        canvas.remove(objects[i]);
    }
    RenderCanvas();
}                                                                                                             But this is removing other lines also, which is not desirable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a group of grids then add to canvas, while removing remove the group object;

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
  width: 600,
  height: 600
})
var gridGroup;

function addGrid() {
  if (gridGroup) return;
  var gridsize = 5;
  var gridoption = {
    stroke: "#000000",
    strokeWidth: 1,
    strokeDashArray: [5, 5]
  };
  var gridLines = [];
  for (var x = 1; x < (canvas.width); x += 100) {
    gridLines.push(new fabric.Line([x, 0, x, canvas.width], gridoption));
  }
  for (var x = 1; x < (canvas.height); x += 100) {
    gridLines.push(new fabric.Line([0, x, canvas.height, x], gridoption));
  }
  gridGroup = new fabric.Group(gridLines, {
    selectable: false,
    evented: false
  })
  gridGroup.addWithUpdate();
  canvas.add(gridGroup);
}

function removeGrid() {
  gridGroup && canvas.remove(gridGroup);
  gridGroup = null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick='addGrid()'>Add</button>
<button onclick='removeGrid()'>Remove</button>
<canvas id="c" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```